# Azure Function Route Parameter is null

Tags: .net, azure, routes, azure-functions

I have an azure function like so:

```
    [FunctionName("MaterialsByMaterialNumber")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "MaterialsByMaterialNumber/{warehouseId}/{materialNumber:int}")]
        string warehouseId, int materialNumber, HttpRequest req, ILogger log, [Inject(typeof(IQueryService))]QueryService queryService)
    {
        log.LogInformation("MaterialsByRollId function is processing a request");
        IEnumerable<BarcodedMaterial> result = await queryService.GetMaterialsByMaterialNumberAsync(materialNumber, warehouseId);
        return result != null ?
            (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(result) :
            new BadRequestObjectResult("Something went wrong with this request");
    }
```

Locally, I request the function with the url: `http://localhost:7071/api/MaterialsByMaterialNumber/4072B201-C0A1-4955-815E-7D13953C8C0C/9300`

When viewing in the debugger, my warehouseId is always null, while my materialNumber is always populated. Does anyone know what is up with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you missed one thing: you've added an attribute to string warehouseId instead of HttpRequest req.

Comment: Thanks! This lead me to the solutions which was that the httpReq req was out of order as the function parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I test both azure function v1 and v2 with following code, it works correctly on my side. For more information about adding parameters to function routes, we could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/routes?tabs=csharp#adding-parameters-to-function-routes).

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, 
    "get", 
    "post", 
    Route = "test/{warehouseId}/{materialNumber:int}")]
  HttpRequestMessage req, 
  string warehouseId, 
  int materialNumber, 
  TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"warehouseId:{warehouseId},materialNumber:{materialNumber}");
}
```

I recommend that you could create a new azure function just with parameters that I mentioned and then add your customized parameters to Azure function one by one to debug it.

**Test Result:**

[image]